# Need help with PPPoE Subscriber Management on a MX80

Tags: juniper, pppoe, radius, juniper-mx

I've been working with Subscriber Management using DHCP and a FreeRadius server and have been quite successful. Of course, once my company heard that it is possible for customers to bring their public IP address with them to another location, I get to work on this matter :-)

All relevant configuration is below. I feel I'm very close to the solution, but I just need the final 2%.

A) The MX80 is able to reach the FreeRadius server;

B) If I deactivate ppp-options { pap } and have a DHCP pool configured, then the client just gets an IP address from the pool. This is not what I want. I want to specify the IP address per customer.

C) Debugging the FreeRadius actions (freeradius -X) I can see that the user is authenticated successfully with given password. What do I need to send back to the Juniper? Framed-IP-Address I suppose, I use this for DHCP as well. The address just doesn't get bound to the dynamic pp0 interface.

```
DYNINTF-PPPOE-TEST {
    routing-instances {
        "$junos-routing-instance" {
            interface "$junos-interface-name";
            routing-options {
                access {
                    route $junos-framed-route-ip-address-prefix {
                        next-hop "$junos-framed-route-nexthop";
                        preference 4;
                    }
                }
                access-internal {
                    route $junos-subscriber-ip-address {
                        qualified-next-hop "$junos-interface-name";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    interfaces {
        pp0 {
            unit "$junos-interface-unit" {
                ppp-options {
                    pap;
                }
                pppoe-options {
                    underlying-interface "$junos-underlying-interface";
                    server;
                }
                keepalives interval 60;
                family inet {
                    unnumbered-address "$junos-loopback-interface";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
VLAN-PROFILE {
    interfaces {
        demux0 {
            unit "$junos-interface-unit" {
                proxy-arp;
                vlan-id "$junos-vlan-id";
                demux-options {
                    underlying-interface "$junos-interface-ifd-name";
                }
                family pppoe {
                    duplicate-protection;
                    dynamic-profile DYNINTF-PPPOE-TEST;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

access-profile local;

interfaces {
    ge-1/1/1 {
        description "PPPoE test interface";
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        auto-configure {
            vlan-ranges {
                dynamic-profile VLAN-PROFILE {
                    accept pppoe;
                    ranges {
                        any;
                    }
                }
                access-profile access-test-profile;
            }
        }
        encapsulation flexible-ethernet-services;
    }
    lo0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.120.120.1/32;
            }
        }
    }
}

access {
    radius-server {
        xxxx {
            secret ""; ## SECRET-DATA
            source-address xxxx;
        }
    }
    domain-name-server {
        xxxx;
        xxxx;
    }
    profile local {
        accounting-order radius;
        authentication-order radius;
        radius {
            authentication-server xxxx;
            accounting-server xxxx;
        }
        radius-server {
            xxxx {
                secret ""; ## SECRET-DATA
                source-address xxxx;
            }
        }
        accounting {                    
            order radius;
        }
    }
    profile access-test-profile {
        authentication-order radius;
        radius {
            authentication-server xxxx;
        }
        radius-server {
            xxxx {
                secret ""; ## SECRET-DATA
                source-address xxxx;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need Framed-IP-Address for sure. According to the configuration which you are using I am not sure what other parameters you will need to configure.

In order to use PAP/CHAP authentication you have to configure Cleartext-Password in your freeradius.